# Increment variable in template v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have such pseudo-vue-js loop:

```
var j = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
    <item-component></item-component>

    if(i % 10 === 0){
        <component :is="'advertising-block-' + j"></component>
        j ++;
    }
}
```

How to override it to vue template?

I need to show different advertising block after each tenth items and name of such component (block) should be:

```
advertising-block-0
advertising-block-1
...
advertising-block-10 (last one after 100th item).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `v-for` to iterate 100 times, and after every tenth item show an advertising component (this should be a common one that takes `j` and show the corresponding item) using `v-if`:

```js
const itemcomponent = Vue.component('itemcomponent', {
  template: '#itemcomponent',
});
const advertisingblock = Vue.component('advertisingblock', {
  template: '#advertisingblock',
  props: ['id']
});

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  components: { itemcomponent, advertisingblock }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template id="itemcomponent">
  <div>item</div>
</template>

<template id="advertisingblock">
  <div>advertising-block-{{id}}</div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i in 100">
    <div><itemcomponent/></div>
    <div v-if="i%10===0"><advertisingblock :id="i/10"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any reason you haven't key property to your v-for ?